# ListView subclass with custom adapter: basic Java Q

Tags: java, android, listview

I am creating a subclass of **ListView** which needs a specialized adapter that subclasses **ListAdapter** (**CustomAdapter**). I want to retain the **setAdapter** and **getAdapter** methods as they are standard methods which programmers expect to use with an **AdapterView**.

I can override the getter:

```
@Override
public CustomAdapter getAdapter() {...}
```

as it still returns a ListAdapter. However, I cannot override the setter:

```
@Override 
public void setAdapter(CustomAdapter adapter) {...}
```

I get why Java won't let me do this. So to get around it, right now, I do this:

```
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("adapter must be an instance of CustomAdapter");
}

public void setAdapter(CustomAdapter adapter) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
}
```

I don't think this is a big deal, but it sort of bugs me. It seems inelegant to still expose the original ListAdapter setter (esp. since it shows up in autocomplete lists). Is there any way to suppress the original setter, or is the above block the correct way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm interested in what is special about CustomAdapter that the ListAdapter impls cannot do?

Comment: the custom listView is a drilldown list, so the customAdapter needs to expose methods to move up or down in the data hierarchy (among other things related to lazy fetching of data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not

```
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if (adapter instanceof CustomAdapter) {
        this.adapter = (CustomAdapter adapter)
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("adapter must be an instance of CustomAdapter");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) but the app developer using my view would have no idea I'm expecting a customAdapter until they get the error (or read my documentation)

Comment: Yep, but your request goes against OOP. You can't hide parent methods, because someone can assign your CustomListView to ListView and fail to use ListAdapter: `ListView lv = new CustomListView(); lv.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(...));` Maybe you should not subclass, but incapsulate ListView and provide you own interface.